# IOS use CoreData MR_findByAttribute

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

I'm using `MagicalRecord` to save my data.

I want to get 2 columns with 2 values

So, I cannot use this method:

```
[MyData MR_findByAttribute:(NSString *) withValue:(id)]
```

How to I can 2 columns with 2 values use `MagicalRecord`

Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use another fetch method with NSPredicate:

```
NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"atribute1=%@ AND attribute2=%@", value1, value2];
NSArray *result = [Model MR_findAllWithPredicate: filter];
```

take a look at [this article](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/blob/master/Docs/Fetching-Entities.md)